# How to create file download popup form in drupal7

Tags: drupal-7, popup, download

I am new to drupal. I want to create a popup form with Name,Email Fields,Download and close button when user click the download link the popup form want to display then user give the name and email after the validation the file have been download by user and also how many user have downloaded how can i dot his

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Webform protected downloads](https://drupal.org/project/webform_protected_downloads) module, which prompt the user to fill atleast an email field before downloading the file. You can add as many files you want. Please see this answer [Fill form before download](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28810/setting-up-a-download-page-requiring-a-user-to-fill-a-form-before-downloading-an)

If you want to do this manually, create a [webform](https://drupal.org/project/webform) with necessary fields and you can use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). In you template.php,

```
    function YOUR_THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
        if($form_id == "YOUR_WEBFORM_ID")
        {
            $form['#submit'][] = 'download_file';
        }
    }

    function download_file(){

        $file_path = variable_get('file_public_path', conf_path() . '/files');
        $file_name = $file_path."/YOUR_FILE";
        $file = fopen($file_name, 'r');
        $file_size = filesize($file_name);

        header("Content-type: application/pdf"); // add here more headers for diff. extensions
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
        header("Content-Type: application/download");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".  urlencode('FILENAME')."\""); // use 'attachment' to force a download
        header("Content-length: $file_size");
        header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly
        while(!feof($file)) {
             $buffer = fread($file, 2048);
             echo $buffer;
             flush();
        }
        $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        header('Location:'. $url);
        fclose ($file);
}
```

This will download the file on submitting the form.

To make the form as pop up, make the form available as block under form settings and put the form block in any jQuery plugin like [thickbox](http://codylindley.com/thickbox/).

Comment: nice code, which required in drupal hook. but the prob is after file downloaded control not going back to form. any valuable suggestion to this problem.

Comment: Interested in same thing as you @Bharanikumar, also I need to add the file from admin, do you know any way of doing that?